# How is a recovery partition handled by Ubuntu and Grub2 during and after installation?

Tags: grub2

I have an Acer Aspire 5332 computer and I’m running Windows Vista. I plan to install Ubuntu 16.04 manually through 'Something Else'. I want to delete Windows during the install but preserve its recovery partition (Acer's EISA Configuration). Then I want to create a root ’/ ‘ partition and a swap partition and select Grub's /dev/sda boot setting. I understand that with this setting Grub will recognise everything on my hard drive but will boot Ubuntu automatically by default. Is this correct?

Also, I've seen screenshots of the Grub boot screen showing a Windows’ recovery partition listed on the screen, and I was wondering how Grub and Ubuntu handle these partitions. For instance, upon start-up, will my computer go straight into Ubuntu's splash screen or the Grub boot screen (like a dual boot)?

Finally, if the recovery partition is listed on the Grub boot screen, can it be accessed through this screen, although I'm assuming that the recovery partition doesn't have a  Master Boot Record for Grub to over-write. And failing this option, will I still be able to access my recovery partition by using Acer's default keys 'Alt' and 'F10'? - I'm assuming that the Ubuntu/Grub install won't affect this function nor corrupt the Windows recovery software. But am I right in thinking this?

My install details will be as follows:-

I have a normal Motherboard Bios (Brand Acer V1.06 ) .

The Acer recovery partition (PQ Service/EISA Configuration) contains a factory setting image of Vista.

After deleting my Windows NTFS partition (Vista) during manual install (’Something Else‘), my new partition table will be as follows:-

dev/sda1 - recovery partition

dev/sda2 - root ‘/’ (EXT4)

dev/sda3 - swap

Boot selection -

dev/sda (for the whole drive).

Comment: When your hard drive totally fails a recovery partition on drive does not help to restore to your new drive. Better to make the DVD set or flash drive image that it should have you make. Usually recovery partitions have Windows boot loaders and grub can chain to those. Grub looks for bootmgr & BCD to know bootable partitions. Windows uses boot flag, but recovery partition does not have boot flag as only Windows partition can have it.